# Use variable in markdown to represent url base

Tags: html, markdown

I have a readme.md file, looks like this:

```
## Utility Methods
> Links to the documentation

### Control Flow

* [Series](https://www.google.com/dingo)
* [Parallel](https://www.google.com/fondue)
* [Waterfall](https://www.google.com/ok)
* [Inject](https://www.google.com/foop) - (most recommended)
```

I am looking to do something like this to make it more maintainable:

```
%url=https://www.google.com  # define variable?

## Utility Methods
> Links to the documentation

### Control Flow

* [Series](%url/dingo)
* [Parallel](%url/fondue)/[ParallelLimit](%url/sram) 
* [Waterfall](%url/ok)
* [Inject](%url/foop) - (most recommended)
```

As you can see I am trying to reduce the amount of times I repeat the url base. In reality my url-base is a lot longer than google.com, it's 3 or 4x longer so it's much worse.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio/issues/158) could be of some help.

Comment: Yeah making a pre-processor and using templates might be the way to go. Although I do think that markdown readers / interpretators would be capable of doing this tho, technically speaking

Comment: Markdown was [originally envisioned as a way to write prose](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and it was deliberately limited in what it could do. It doesn't do anything like this _by design_, though that hasn't stopped other people from implementing Markdown-like languages that do more. The processor you're using will be important if you expect to get a helpful answer here.

Comment: yeah in this case Github flavored markdown is what I am going for

Comment: That doesn't answer @Chris's question. Which tool are you using? Lots of tools can process GFM, but not all can do what you want.

Comment: I just found an example [lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#replacing-placeholders-with-their-metadata-value) in the Pandoc documentation which does this. You might find some more solutions (such as the [pandoc-mustache filter](https://github.com/michaelstepner/pandoc-mustache)) in the [Pandoc issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1950) requesting this feature.

Comment: @Waylan `lua-filter` did not work for links, I used: `[Studienwebsite](%vinf%)` and defined it `---vinf: https://www.verwaltungsinformatiker.de
---` and included the meta-lua-file. For other variables not links it works.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai the question addresses `links` and not general substitution. Replacing links is probably not (yet) possible with md, although I dit not try @waylan solution with python..

Answer (score 1):

Markdown has no variable / macro / template feature.

So you need to do the substitution when creating your markdown file(s).

A common practice is to have a set of "template" markdown files and use a tool (e.g. Perl) to substitute your keywords with their final values to instanciate a final set of markdown files.

[Here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10174) is another way to achieve this using JavaScript.